# Ninject getting a generic type in ToMethod

Tags: ninject

I have a repository like this:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ISession session;

    public Repository(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }
}
```

I use [NHQS](http://www.bradygaster.com/nhqs) and I usually do this to get a ISession object:

```
SessionFactory.For<T>().OpenSession();
```

How do I setup Ninject to create a session automatically for the requested type and bind it? I tried this but I don't know what to put in the For<>():

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .To(typeof(Repository<>))
    .WithConstructorArgument("session", SessionFactory.For<>().OpenSession());
```

Looks like I need to get the generic type being used and pass it in the For<>()

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should'nt use `WithConstructorArgument`; create a binding for ISession instead.

```
kernel.Bind<ISession>.ToMethod(context => ....).InRequestScope();
```

You can get the `IRepository<>` type from `context.Request.ParentRequest.Service`. You can now extract the entity type using reflection. However, if you are using the same database for all entities then it is probably easier to return a general session for all repositories.